# Is the kinetic energy $T=\frac{p^2}{2 m}$ always valid?

Tags: special-relativity, energy, momentum

As the title states, Is $T=p^2 / 2 m$, where $T$ is the kinetic energy, $p$ is the norm of the 4-momentum, and $m$ is mass, always valid? My main intuition is that $T$ may not be relativistic; although, I assume it is relativistic because $p^2$ could be written as $p_{\mu } p^{\mu }$ which is $g_{\mu \nu } p^{\mu } p^{\nu }$. This seems to be relativistic and seems to work in the expression for $T$.

Additionally, will the expression for mass need to be made relativistic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. In special relativity energy is given by $$E = \sqrt{(pc)^2 + (mc^2)^2},$$ so the kinetic energy is given by:
$$T = \sqrt{(pc)^2 + (mc^2)^2} - mc^2.$$ When $pc \ll mc^2$ you can do a Taylor expansion to get:
$$T \approx \frac{p^2}{2m} - \frac{p^4}{8 m^3 c^2} + \ldots .$$
When you do it in the high momentum limit $pc \gg mc^2$ you get:
$$T \approx -mc^2 + pc + \frac{m^2c^3}{2 p} + \ldots. $$

Comment: Thank you for this response. I love how you included the Taylor expansion to derive a low momentum expression. One of my (not-stated) inquiries was about if somehow the S.R. expression for $T$ could be derived from $p^2/2m$; you answered this with Taylor expansion form.